# Estimate for the limit of the solution of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have this system:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=-axy\\
\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=axy-by\\
\frac{d}{dt}z(t)=by
\end{cases}
 $$

Let be:

- $x+y+z=1$ for every $t$
- $a>b$ and $a,b$ strictly positive
- y(0)>0

I need to proove that:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}z\geq1-\frac{b}{a}$$

My thoughts are:

- because $x+y+z=1$, I can study the system with only 2 equations
- it exist a finite limit for the system when t is going to infinity
- maybe "reductio ab absurdo" could be the best strategy, but I cannot get it

Any hint, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any thing on sign of $a,b$?

Comment: Is sorry, they are strictly positive. I'm correcting it.

Comment: Let u = x+y, so you want to show lim u <= b/a. The first two equations say that u' = -b(u-x) and x' = -ax(u-x), so u' = b/a * x'/x. So u = b/a ln x + c which would be <= b/a if c were 0 and x were <= e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice system. I think of it in terms of transfer of mass in a chemical reaction. The total mass of elements $x,y,z$ remains constant. Element $y$ decays at relative rate $b$, producing $z$. Element $x$ reacts with $y$ at a  rate proportional to the product of their masses. As a result of reaction, $x$ turns into $y$.

At first it looks like everything will become $z$  eventually, that is $z\to 1$ as $t\to\infty$. But if $y$ becomes depleted, the conversion of $x$ to $y$ shuts down; this is something for us consider.

But since $y'=(ax-b)y$,   the quantity of $y$ will not decrease until $x$ drops below $b/a$. At that moment we already have  $y+z\ge 1-b/a$, and all of this amount will become $z$ eventually. Hence the result.

It remains  to somehow express this mathematically. Here is one way, behind a spoiler.

> None of $x,y,z$ can become negative; hence none of them can exceed $1$. The function $y$ must have $\liminf_{t\to\infty} y(t)=0$ because otherwise $z$ would tend to infinity. Therefore, there is $t$ such that $y'(t)<0$. At this $t$ we have $x(t)<b/a$, hence $y(t)+z(t)\ge 1-b/a$. Since $y+z$ does not decrease, and $\liminf_{t\to\infty} y(t)=0$, we have $\limsup_{t\to\infty} z(t)\ge 1-b/a$. But $z$ is increasing, so $\limsup$ is $\lim$.